# NextJS 14 i18n cannot detected static assets, favicon, robots txt with

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, next.js13, i18next

I cannot access the static assets. I used NextJS 14 with app routes & src folder. But i cannot access.
I try to copy this template [template i18n from nextJS](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/app-dir-i18n-routing) but i change with src folder.

This is my Middleware:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

import { i18n } from '@/i18n/i18n-config';

import { match as matchLocale } from '@formatjs/intl-localematcher';
import Negotiator from 'negotiator';

function getLocale(request: NextRequest): string | undefined {
  // Negotiator expects plain object so we need to transform headers
  const negotiatorHeaders: Record<string, string> = {};
  request.headers.forEach((value, key) => (negotiatorHeaders[key] = value));

  // @ts-ignore locales are readonly
  const locales: string[] = i18n.locales;

  // Use negotiator and intl-localematcher to get best locale
  let languages = new Negotiator({ headers: negotiatorHeaders }).languages(
    locales
  );

  const locale = matchLocale(languages, locales, i18n.defaultLocale);

  return locale;
}

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname;

  // // `/_next/` and `/api/` are ignored by the watcher, but we need to ignore files in `public` manually.
  // // If you have one
  // if (
  //   [
  //     '/manifest.json',
  //     '/favicon.ico',
  //     // Your other files in `public`
  //   ].includes(pathname)
  // )
  //   return

  // Check if there is any supported locale in the pathname
  const pathnameIsMissingLocale = i18n.locales.every(
    (locale) => !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale}`
  );

  // Redirect if there is no locale
  if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
    const locale = 'id';

    // e.g. incoming request is /products
    // The new URL is now /en-US/products
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(
        `/${locale}${pathname.startsWith('/') ? '' : '/'}${pathname}`,
        request.url
      )
    );
  }
}

export const config = {
  // Matcher ignoring `/_next/` and `/api/`
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)'],
};
```

This is the folder routes images[image: Image Folder Routes]

I try to change middleware matcher with

```
matcher: [
"/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|img/|favicon.ico).*)",
]
```

but idk why the solution didn't work